# How to send fake JSON data in a Rails response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

I know we can generate fake data with [faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) in Ruby.

I want to send fake data from the API in the response. Currently, I generated a dummy response in the `public/data.json` file which has only three static objects.

```
def dummy_response
 data = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/data.json")
 render :json => data, status: 200
end
```

I have to send 100 dummy objects with random values. Can I use the `yml` file to send dummy data or with faker gem generate dummy JSON and send it back in response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
data_hash = {}
100.times { |x| data_hash[x] = { name: Faker::Name.first_name } }
render json: data_hash.to_json, status: 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Chuck Norris can use the [Faker gem](https://github.com/stympy/faker/).

```
def dummy_response
 data = {fact: Faker::ChuckNorris.fact}
 render :json => data, status: 200
end
```